# Prisma return type in a custom service function

Tags: node.js, prisma

When using prisma directly to find a user record, we can specify what relations to include, example:

```
const user = await prisma.user.findFirst({where: {id: 'something'}, include: {profile: true}})

user.profile <-- exists
```

when using a custom service method, the return type won't include the relation that is selected:

```
const findOne = (args: Prisma.UserFindFirstArgs) => {
  return client.user.findFirst(args);
};

const user = await findOne({where: {id: 'something'}, include: {profile: true}})

user.profile <-- doesn't exist
```

Comment: Related https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/20816#issuecomment-1873448080

Answer (score 0):

wondering the exact same thing! this is a feature prisma should add